# Proof that there is no autocorrelation

Tags: autocorrelation

I was wondering whether my reasoning is correct and whether I've written it down correctly:

Given the following equation $bread_i=\beta_{0} + \beta_{1}wage + u_{t}$, where $u_{t}$ is normally distributed with a mean of zero and a variancce of $\sigma^{2}$ and is independent of $wage$.

Furthermore we know that there is no autocorrelation, $bread$ and $wage$ are not cointegrated, however there is a unit root present in $bread$ and $wage$.

Given a first difference model $\Delta bread_{t} = \beta_1 \Delta wage_{t}+\epsilon_{t}$, where $\epsilon = \Delta u_{t}$. Is the error term $\epsilon_{t}$ in this equation uncorrelated over time? Please motivate your answer with a formal derivation.

Well I thought the following:

Since $\epsilon = u_{t} - u_{t-1}$ and we know that there is no autocorrelation between them, after first differencing there will be no autocorrelation afterwards.

Question is of course how to show it? Using COV maybe? I am currently trying to derive it, but I'm a bit stuck.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I meant: there is a unit root present in the time series of $y$ and there is a unit root present in the time series of $x$.

Comment: I assume your solution would give me that the error terms are uncorrelated over time. However if I checked whether $Corr(e_{t}, e_{t-1}) = 0$ I got that $Corr(e_{t}, e_{t-1}) = -Var(wage)$. Which indicate that they are correlated. Can you tell me what I did wrong?

Comment: The derivation I did was the following:

$Corr(e_{t}, e_{t-1}) = Cov(u_{t} - u_{t-1}, u_{t-1} - u_{t}) \cdot \frac{1}{\sigma_{x}\sigma_{y}}$
$= Cov(u_{t}, _{t-1}) - Cov(u_{t}, u_{t-2}) - Cov(u_{t-1}, u_{t-1}) + Cov(u_{t-1}, u_{t-2}) \cdot \frac{1}{\sigma_{x}\sigma_{y}}$
Now we know that $u_{t}$ is not correlated with $u_{t-1}$, so they become zero. However I am not sure about $Cov(u_{t}, u_{t-2})$, that should be zero too I guess since $u_{t}$ is uncorrelated with all $u_{t}$.
$ = - Cov(u_{t-1}, u_{t-1}) \cdot \frac{1}{\sigma_{x}\sigma_{y}}$
$ = -Var(X) \cdot \frac{1}{\sigma_{x}\sigma_{y}}$

Comment: $ = -\sigma_{x}^{2} \cdot \frac{1}{\sigma_{x}\sigma_{y}}$
$ = - \frac{\sigma_{x}}{\sigma_{y}}$

So this shows that $e_{t}$ and $e_{t-1}$ are indeed correlated right?

Comment: PS: maybe I'm a bit confused, but what has unit root actually to do with autoccorrelation?

Comment: The presence of a unit root in both series makes the corresponding first-differenced series into white noises. Then any assumed relation between $\Delta y_t$ and $\Delta x_t$ is essentially a relation between two white noises. Since we assume that there is no co-integration in levels, this means that $u_t$ is not stationary - but I showed that it must be $I(1)$, i.e. integrated of order 1, i.e. $\Delta u_t$ is stationary -and not autocorrelated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will just use $y$ for bread and $x$ for wage. You write that "a unit root is present in both $y$ and $x$." Although this is rather vague, let's say that we have

$$y_t=y_{t-1}+v_t,\Rightarrow \Delta y_t = v_t$$
$$ x_t=x_{t-1}+\omega_t \Rightarrow \Delta x_t = \omega_t$$

with $v_t$ and $\omega_t$ independent white noises.

Then in the first difference specification
$$\Delta y_t=\beta_{1}\Delta x_t + \Delta u_{t}$$ 
we substitute using the expressions for $\Delta y_t$ and $\Delta x_t$ to obtain

$$v_t=\beta_{1}\omega_t + \Delta u_{t} \Rightarrow v_t-\beta_1\omega_t = \Delta u_t$$

So $\Delta u_t$ is a linear combination of independent white noises, and therefore white noise itself.

**ADDENDUM**

$$\operatorname {Cov}(\Delta u_t, \Delta u_{t-1}) = E\left( \Delta u_t\Delta u_{t-1}\right)  = E\left( ( v_t-\beta_1\omega_t)( v_{t-1}-\beta_1\omega_{t-1})\right)$$
$$=E(v_tv_{t-1})-\beta_1E(v_t\omega_{t-1})-\beta_1E(\omega_t v_{t-1})+ \beta_1^2E(\omega_t\omega_{t-1})$$
$$=0+0+0+0=0$$
since we have white noises, and independent between them.